# What is the CoroutineScope of runBlocking in Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the CoroutineScope of

```
runBlocking {
 // some code here
}
```

in Kotlin Coroutines?

Is it local to the class where it is called and the Coroutine is garbage collected when the Class is garbage collected or will it cause memory leak if its still running?

Comment: runBlocking is a bridge between normal code and coroutines. It blocks the thread it is called from. Coroutines are not threads, a coroutine can start work on a thread and finish it in another. The coroutine scope by using `this` is just that thread coroutine scope, and you can use any other inside the code block.  To answer your question, the coroutine running inside runBlocking should stop if its scope is destroyed, but this should never be used in a real world example because usually runBlocking should only be on top level, like in the main function.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) or [async](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html), `runBlocking` is a very special coroutine builder because it is supposed to be used at the top-level. It is therefore not run *inside* a scope (there is no `CoroutineScope` as receiver as you can see). It is rather meant to be a "root" of structured concurrency.

`runBlocking` actually *provides* you with a scope, so you can start "child" coroutines inside it. What really matters is that `runBlocking` will wait for all coroutines that you start in that scope (child coroutines) to finish before returning.

#### Cancelling runBlocking?

You cannot really cancel the `runBlocking` coroutine itself externally if it hangs (like you would do by cancelling the scope of `launch` or `async`), because it's not an async task - it's blocking a thread. You could interrupt the thread running it, or you could also keep track of nested coroutines and cancel *them* explicitly to make `runBlocking` finish.

A `runBlocking` call will only return once all child coroutines have completed (or were cancelled). Throwing an exception (from inside) also cancels all child coroutines and makes `runBlocking` rethrow that exception. So it's also a way to "cancel" `runBlocking` from inside.

> Is it local to the class where it is called and the Coroutine is garbage collected when the Class is garbage collected or will it cause memory leak if its still running?

You could see `runBlocking` as any blocking function, like `Thread.sleep`, there is no more magic. Just like `Thread.sleep`, `runBlocking` can be called from any function, even top-level, in which case there wouldn't be any class instance involved.

Let's assume a method in a class calls `runBlocking`, and whatever is inside `runBlocking` hangs for a long time (like a long sleep). Then, whoever is calling this method holds a reference to the instance until the method returns or fails, so the instance won't be garbage collected anyway. In this case the caller will hang, blocking whatever thread it's running in - that's where leaks can happen.

#### Examples of problems with runBlocking

##### Spring controller

If you use `runblocking` in the methods of a Spring MVC controller, Spring could be creating threads for each of those, and if anything hangs inside `runBlocking` you kinda leak the thread. Instead, you can use Spring WebFlux which allows you to use `suspend` functions directly in your Spring controllers (and add a request timeout to automatically cancel the hanging stuff).

##### Callbacks

Using `runBlocking` inside callbacks might be dangerous too. The hypothetical callback-based API you're using might be using a thread pool to call you back, and if `runBlocking` hangs it could be blocking that thread pool.

If that API supports backpressure, it might be OK to block though. The API could also support this in a non-blocking way (like JDK11's [websocket listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.Listener.html) which let you return a `CompletableStage` from the callbacks), in which case you should should build a `Future` instead of blocking.

If the API doesn't support backpressure, you might have to resort to creating a custom `CoroutineScope` and `launch`-ing coroutines in it to handle the callbacks (instead of `runBlocking`). You'll have to cancel that scope manually when you're not using the callback based API anymore.

Comment: I believe the main point of OP is that we have some kind of a service, it runs coroutines with `runBlocking()` and then we remove all references to this service. The question is: will it leak background tasks? Is it safe to design the code like this? I believe the answer is: no, it is not safe. We can't stop coroutines by somehow removing all references to them. We always need to explicitly cancel them. Moreover, the service won't be really GC'ed, because the thread blocked on `runBlocking()` will keep a reference to it.

Comment: But calling `runBlocking` won't return until it's done, so it can never leak anything. Because what I would call a leak is giving back control flow without cleaning up resources. The only thing that can leak is whatever is running `runBlocking`, for instance if it's spawning threads to run it, but that's another topic. *We always need to explicitly cancel them.* - actually, no, waiting for `runBlocking` to return is sufficient to guarantee all coroutines are done without explicit cancellation.

Comment: Edited my question. This is new question: Is it local to the class where it is called and the Coroutine is garbage collected when the Class is garbage collected or will it cause a memory leak if it's still running? @Joffrey

Comment: @Gissipi_453 I tried to edit my answer to address your concerns, and clarify what I meant by my comment above. Please let me know if something is still unclear.